# how can i hide columns in dataGrid MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Hi all I'm trying to hide Id columns in MUI but it did't work anyone has idea to do this I try everything litterlay and there is other way to delete by id in dataGrid without put the id in dataGrid

i try to hide columns in dataGrid

Comment: Could you add some code to your question using [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)? Currently its hard to recreate your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an object with the column name and a value of false to `initialState` > `columns` > `columnVisibilityModel` property.

**Exmaple:**

```
<DataGrid
  initialState={{
    columns: {
      columnVisibilityModel: {
        // Hide columns id and lastname.
        // Other columns will remain visible
        id: false,
        lastname: false,
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

You can look at the [Data Grid - Column visibility](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/) documentation for more options.